# 5 Monitor Setup - Video card issues

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, hdmi, dvi

Dont play games, dont render and I have 4 monitors (all HDMI and all-max 1920x1080), so I got myself a GT 710 (4x HDMI). Does the job perfectly and I am good with that.

Things start to fall apart afterwards though;
So I want to get another (5th monitor). So I got myself a another max-1920x1080 monitor.
As for the graphics card, i got a GTX1650. Worked for a bit but then win10 started crashing frequently, and performance was worse (worse than 1 single gt710) on both cards/all monitors

Then I tried : only GTX 1650 with the DP port and StarTech.com 4 Port Mini DisplayPort MST Hub + HDMI port or the DVI port. 5th monitor wouldnt work.

Then I got 2x GT730 with 4xHDMI each. Same, the performance was worse than single gt710/gt730 - returned

Then, I tried; VisionTek Radeon 7750 2GB GDDR5 (6x mDP ports) :
Unfortunately, card didnt work on any of the MB slots - returned

Then I tried; Nvidia Quadro K2000 Graphics Card 2x DisplayPort and with 2x StarTech.com 3-Port Multi Monitor Adapters. The 5th Monitor wouldnt work.
Lastly, I tried; Nvidia Quadro K2000 Graphics Card 2x DisplayPort and with 2x StarTech.com 3-HDMI Port Multi Monitor Adapters. The 5th Monitor wouldnt work.

If I change the order of the monitors, I can get up to 4 (random) monitors to work but never the 5th (again-random).

So I currently have the GT710 and the Quadro K2000 with 2xDP.

And my;
MB: http://www.huananzhi.com/html/1/184/185/456.html
CPU: 2x E-2678v3

Any ideas as to how to get 5 HDMI monitors to work?
(extended ofc)

Comment: That title can be a bit misleading if you are specifically looking for HDMI, and not VGA.

Comment: Thanks, sorry about that, fixed it...

Comment: Make sure to check the specs! Any single card is often limited to 4 concurrently active displays. Still, it should've worked with multiple cards. Special cards that support more exist, too.